# How to replace OAuth2 in Spring Boot 3?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

I have read a lot about this topic but I have not found a solution to whether to replace what was used or create new methods or if there is a new dependency that can help me, referring to the deprecation of OAuth2 and JWT security.

I use methods like:

```
TokenStore 
OAuth2AuthenticationDetails
OAuth2AccessToken
DefaultTokenServices
JwtAccessTokenConverter
JwtTokenStore
```

that helped me recover data from a session token, I don't know if there is any other dependency or other methods to recover this data?

Comment: have you opened [the manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/)? Do you know if you want to configure a client (sending requests to access REST resources) or a resource-server (responding to those requests)?

Comment: @ch4mp this looks like the authorization-server. I'm looking for the same answers.

Comment: Since Spring Security 5 OAuth 2 (client and resource server) is built-in. For authorisation server you need an additional dependency.